# npm install && npm run dev isnt working in laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, npm-install

hi i just install the node.js and try to run this command in laravel 8

> npm install && npm run dev

(note: i install node.js in D:)
This is the complete installation

> paste.ofcode.org/ZC8e7KP6v7gYrAxqHBFjpk

but it gives this error:

```
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
  logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs
  \2021-04-24T07_04_58_823Z-debug.log
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
  logging output above.
  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs
  \2021-04-24T07_04_59_173Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What is your Laravel version?

Comment: *There is likely additional logging output above.* Is there? Can you share that if yes?

Comment: laravel version:8

Comment: @apokryfos    this is complete installation paste.ofcode.org/ZC8e7KP6v7gYrAxqHBFjpk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to update your node.js file and then run "npm run dev" and if you again faced the same problem follow the following steps:

```
Step1: composer update
Step2: rm -rf node_modules
Step3: npm cache clean
Step4: npm install
Step5: npm outdated
```

In this step, it will update your laravel-mix version, it is in the package.json.

```
Step6: npm install
Step7: npm run dev
```

After all these steps, everything is good. I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install `git bash` for Windows and navigate to the project directory.

Right-click in the folder and select `git bash here`.

After that, you can run

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

on your Git Bash window.

(Nevermind what version of nodejs u use, cause we know that is very hard to run the new version of nodejs on windows7, so this solution for me working as well)!